# Pseudocode/SQL - building active periods out of activated and deactivated dates?

Tags: database, date, pseudocode

I have a database that includes two tables - SITE and EVENTS (this is all a bit simplified but should be sufficient for pseudocode or a reasonable example in any language).
SITE is not particularly important except that it's the subject of this query, and SITEs can be ACTIVE or INACTIVE, and they have EVENTS happen to them.

The EVENT table has the fields ID, SITEID, EVENTTYPE, EVENTDATE. Common EVENTTYPEs are 'Activated' and 'Deactivated', but they're not the only possible event.
An Site is considered active in between its Activated and Deactivated events. A site may have been activated or deactivated multiple times, but every deactivation is guaranteed to match up with an initial activation.

For every single entity, I want to be able to output the following in a CSV file:

```
Site ID, Activated Date, Deactivated Date
```

Where again, a site may show up multiple times in the file because of being active multiple times. Or, if the site is still active, it will simply read

```
Site ID, Activated Date
```

if it's active at the time of running the program.
What's the appropriate pseudocode/code for matching up these periods efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer thought of - there may be better ones out there, I'm answering my own question!

For each site, select the list of Activations (x), and Deactivations (y) in ascending order.

Because deactivations must have a matching activation, the two lists will form natural (x,y) pairs, with the possibility of a dangling Activation at the end.